# Is it possible to add or extend a note in the middle of the piano roll and have Ableton automatically push the notes to the right

Tags: ableton-live

Like a word processor/text box, if you click in the middle of a sentence and type, it inserts new characters and pushes the characters on the right of the cursor to the right. I want to do the same thing in Ableton. Is this possible? Or if not, can I push the whole score down one 16th note from where the cursor currently is so I don't have to select and move the entire score over and over again

Comment: Sorry to sort of answer my second question but I just noticed the insert time feature which brings up a dialog then i can just put in 0.0.1. But has anyone found an easier way?

Comment: Shouldn't that be "piano roll" instead of "piano role"?

Answer (score 1):

- Open the MIDI clip
- Click on the pencil icon in the top left corner
- Click on the grid at the point where you want to insert new notes
- Press "Tab" on the keyboard to switch to the insert mode